# C++ - Could any help me to translate this for loop to recursion function?

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, recursion, nested-loops

I have an array, table, with some char, a and b.
I want to find and replace the 'b' with 'a' then count how many are replaced. How to write a recursive function equivalent to the nested loop?

```
    const int length = 4;
    char table[length][length] = {
        {'a','b','a','a'},
        {'a','a','a','b'},
        {'a','a','b','a'},
        {'b','b','a','a'}
    };

    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < length; j++) {
            if (table[i][j] == 'b') {
                count++;
                table[i][j] = 'a';
            }
        }
    }
    cout << "Count: " << count << endl;
```

This is what I tried:

```
int replace_char(char array[][length], int row, int col) {
    // base cases and recursive
    if (row+1 != length - 1)
        replace_char(array, row+1, col);
    if (col+1 != length - 1)
        replace_char(array, row, col+1);

    // do this
    if (array[row][col] == 'b') {
        array[row][col] = 'a';
        return 1 + replace_char(array, row, col);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

My idea is, if it's not the end of the col or the row, then go check the next col or row. While checking, if the char is b, then return 1, and start checking from where it stops.
But it is not working.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Also please learn how to create a [mcve] of your own attempt to show us, and describe what problems you have with it. Lastly please note that stackoverflow.com isn't a free coding service.

Comment: Why?  Is this a homework question? what have you tried?

Comment: ⚠️ Careful!  For a small table, this is fine.  For larger or dynamic tables, recursion in C++ is easy to exceed the stack limit because C++ does not (usually) support tail recursion optimization.

Comment: Yes it is from homework and I updated my tried code. It seems the recursion never stops.

Comment: @Eljay at -O2 and -O3 tail recursion should be optimised out.  At least with GCC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very close:

```
int replace_char(char array[][length], int row, int col) {
    if (col == length) {
        return replace_char(array, row + 1, 0); // reach the end of a col increment the
                                                // row by 1 and reset the col.
                                                // We are over the end so return
    }
    if (row == length) {
        // Then we have passed the last row simply return.
        return 0;
    }

    // Now do the work.
    int count = 0;
    if (array[row][col] == 'b') {
        array[row][col] = 'a';
        count = 1;
    }
    // Once you have done the work
    // Make the recursive call.
    return count + replace_char(array, row, col + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The function can be defined the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>

size_t replace_count( char *s, size_t n, char c1 = 'b', char c2 = 'a' )
{
    return n == 0 ? 0 
                  : ( ( *s == c1 ? ( *s = c2, 1 ) : 0 ) + replace_count( s + 1, n - 1, c1, c2 ) );
}

int main() 
{
    const int length = 4;
    char table[length][length] = {
        {'a','b','a','a'},
        {'a','a','a','b'},
        {'a','a','b','a'},
        {'b','b','a','a'}
    };

    std::cout << replace_count( reinterpret_cast<char *>( table ), length * length )
              << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
5
```